# How does the centre tap of a **centre tap transformer** at zero volts?

Tags: electromagnetism, voltage, conventions, electronics, electrical-engineering

As per my knowledge, the secodary coil will have one terminal at positive and another 0(zero) at one instant, and at another cycle, the other terminal becomes positive and the first one become 0(zero). **Because**, in 
case of a half wave rectifier using a diode, when the diode is conducting in one half cycle, the terminal of the coil connected to the 'p' side of the diode is positive(or is of high voltage), and the other one is just 0(zero). Then how come the middle point be at 0(zero) volts in case of a centre tap transformer instead of the other extreme end of the coil?
Please make me clear about the correct underlying physics.

Comment: You can choose any reference point you like to have the potential 0. In a transformer with a central tap it is natural to choose the tap to be at 0 potential (since then the symmetry between the two parts of the coil will be manifest in the equations).

Answer (score 4):

There is no "underlying physics" to this.  It's just how they're usually used: the center tap is connected to the ground so that the two ends become opposite plus and minus voltages. That's useful for many different applications.

There are circuits where one end of the secondary is attached to ground, so that the middle is +/-V and the other end is +/-2V.  That can also be useful.

Answer (score -1):

The mA meter has to be place the furthest away from the high-voltage (found the ends). Which places the thing at zero. It’s more of a safety issue verses anything else.

So if a question asks you, were is there higher voltage, you know it’s the furthest from mA meter.

Comment: It's not clear to me how this answers the question.